# Can I store a logical comparison in a string?

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements, modularity, modularization

I am trying to modularise a lengthy `if..else` function.

```
$condition = "$a < $b";
if($condition)
{
    $c++;
}
```

Is there any way of translating the literal string into a logical expression?

Comment: You *could* do this with `eval`, but the standard approach would be to define a bunch of functions...

Comment: maybe you should explain, what exactly you mean with "modularise".

Comment: Please show your lengthy if..else block (not function). I'm almost sure, the solution isn't 'modularizing'.

Comment: Lenghty if else blocks are often a sign that you're violating some principles of clean coding.

Comment: hence the need to modularise..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I am trying to modularise a lengthy if..else function.

You don't need to put the condition in a string for that, just store the boolean `true` or `false`:

```
$condition = ($a < $b);
if($condition)
{
    $c++;
}
```

> the values of $a and $b may change between definition of $condition and its usage

One solution would be a Closure (assuming that definition and usage are happening in the same scope):

```
$condition = function() use (&$a, &$b) {
    return $a < $b;
}
$a = 1;
$b = 2;
if ($condition()) {
    echo 'a is less than b';
}
```

But I don't know if this makes sense for you without remotely knowing what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: the values of $a and $b may change between definition of $condition and its usage.

Comment: If you remove the part above the closure stuff it would be the best answer (what it already is :) )

Comment: I won't remove it to leave the answer more generalized for future readers. Pick what you need ;)

Comment: You will be happy to hear that you are wrong :) Otherwise my first solution would be perfectly fine. Did you notice the references (`&`) in the use clause?

Answer (score 2):

Use lambda if you know variables that are enough to determine result

```
$f = function ($a, $b) { return $a < $b; }

if ($f($x, $y)){}
```

Comment: +1. Though you don't need lambda here, just a plain old function declaration will do just as well :)

Answer (score 1):

you could do this using [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php). not sure why you wouldn't just evaluate the condition immediately, though.

Comment: `eval` is never the solution of the problem. We should avoid using it.

Answer (score -3):

```
<?php
     $a=0;
     $b=1;
    function resultofcondition()
    {
        global $a,$b;
        return $a<$b;
    }
    if(resultofcondition()){
        echo " You are dumb,";
    }else{
        echo " I am dumb,"; 
    }
    $a=1;
    $b=0;
    if(resultofcondition()){
        echo " You were correct.";
    }else{
        echo " in your face.";
    }
?>
```

Indeed thanks for commenting that out, was missing the GLOBAL parameter, for those who voted down, what would that code output? ¬_¬ w/e have fun xD

Comment: This does not work in PHP, `$a` and `$b` are not available in the function scope.

Comment: @RicardoOrtegaMagaña They most certainly are not, unless you use `global $a, $b;`

Comment: This last comment doesn't add anything useful to the answer.